# How to create a text file In a folder using python?

Tags: python, file, directory

I am trying to create a .txt file in a folder which is not the directory the script is being run from. I have a folder where the script is, and I am able to create the folder in the same directory the script is in but It won't create the text file in the folder. I usually run in to one of two errors: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`or, `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

This is for a password keeper btw, and to prevent five people telling me it's not secure, I am aware of this, this project is purely educational and I always use placeholders.

There are similar questions to this but they are all for java or c++...

Here is my code:

```
def main():
    import os
    import os.path
    abc = open("userpassfile.txt", "r+")
    userpassfile = abc.read().strip().split()
    actCheck = input('Do you already have an account?')
    if (actCheck == 'Yes' or actCheck == 'yes'):
        loginUser = input('What is your username?')
        loginPass = input('What is yout password?')
        if (loginUser and loginPass in userpassfile):
            dirCheck = input('Account Settings? [y/n]')
            if (dirCheck == 'y' or dirCheck == 'Y'):
                print('This function is not working yet!')
                addpassCheck = input('Would you like to add a password?')
                if (addpassCheck == 'yes' or addpassCheck == 'Yes'):
                    abc123 = open(loginUser + '.txt', "r+")
                    huehuehue = abc123.read().strip().split()
                    addpass1 = input('What service is the pass')
                    addPass2 = input('What is the password')
                    abc123.write('(' + addpass1 + ',' + addPass2 + ')' + '\n')

                else:
                    print('hihi')
            else:
                print("hehe")
        else:
            print('Incorrect password or username!')
    else:
        createAct = input('would you like to create one?')
        if (createAct == 'Yes' or createAct == 'yes'):
            save_path = 'C:/Users/Ari Madian/Desktop/Scripts/Python Scripts/Python Password Project'
            createUser = input('What would you like your username to be?:')
            createPass = input('What would you like your password to be?:')
            abc.write(createUser + '\n')
            abc.write(createPass + '\n')
            os.makedirs(createUser)
            completeName = os.path.join(save_path, createUser + ".txt")



main()
```

If you have any questions about my code, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `open` the .txt file in `a` mode or `w` mode. If you open it in `r+` mode the file will not be created since `r+` does not create a file.

`'a'` creates the file if it does not exist but if it does exist it simply adds to it. `'w'`, on the other hand, deletes the existing one and creates a new one. I think you want to use `a` here.

EDIT: I misunderstood the question here. The file was being created in the wrong directory. Just for future reference, if putting a file in a subdirectory, make sure to add `"/"` when seperating them.

Comment: When I try to do this, it gives me this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keeper.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "keeper.py", line 23, in main
    huehuehue = abc123.read().strip().split()
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: You probably have to make sure that the file exists and then open it in `r+` mode. You can't read a file in `a` or `w` mode to my knowledge, forgot to mention that.

Comment: I get the same error when I open it in w mode as I do when I open it in a mode. It creates the file though... It just doesn't create the file in the folder.

Comment: Did you already change the code to reflect checking if the file exists first?
Also, I would advise using `with open(file, extension) as varname` as `with` automatically closes files for you.

Comment: I feel like we got a bit off topic and that was probably my fault... It creates the txt file no problem but not in the folder i want it to be created in.

Comment: Oh... sorry, I misunderstood the question. I thought you were having problems creating the file. Where exactly is it putting the file?

Comment: No problem, I want a folder for every user and when the user adds a new password, it creates a new text file (in their respective folder) with the password Info in it. It is putting the file in the same directory that the script is being run from.

Comment: Is the directory being created and the file not being put in or is the folder not being created at all?

Comment: The user's folder is being created, however, when I try to add a password to that user's file, it creates the text file with the info in it, just not in the User's file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109390/discussion-between-jelly-donuts-and-ari-madian).

Answer (score 0):

The import os and import os.path need to be at the beginning of the program. For example:

```
import os
import os.path
def main():
```

Rather than inside the main(): function.